# dpkg-scanpackages - Packages in archive but missing from override file

Tags: debian, debian-packaging

I have two deb file:

```
<name>_v0.0.10_arm64.deb
<name>_v0.0.10_amd64.deb
```

Note: the architecture difference arm/amd

When I run:

```
dpkg-scanpackages . /dev/null > Release
```

I get:

```
dpkg-scanpackages: warning: Packages in archive but missing from override file:
```

I tried adding `--multiversion` with same result:

```
dpkg-scanpackages --multiversion . /dev/null > Release
```

Then I looked at `--extra-override`, but then it does not work and I have no idea of what I am doing - the doc is not that informative to what an override file is:

```
dpkg-scanpackages --multiversion --extra-override  . /dev/null > Release
```

Do you kno whow to pack multiple deb files(in my case two, one for each architecture)?

Comment: I think you get that message even for a single package. It's been a long time since I did this but IIRC you have to provide it with an explicit overrides file.

Comment: Ok thanks, what is an override file?

Comment: Looking at https://linuxconfig.org/using-debian-package-archive-as-a-configuration-tool I guess it's merely a warning and you can just ignore it.

Comment: Right, I think I will. Thanks

Comment: The manual page has a brief explanation; you are passing `/dev/null` as the override file.

Comment: Ahh ok, that is what I am already doing - well then again, I will ignore it all together

Comment: I mean if you want to remove the warning you need to pass in something more than `/dev/null`. The proper manual is actually https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/deb-override.5.html

Comment: Right I see - cool